# How do i get first date and Last date from month and year |Excel |Used Spinner for Month and Year|

Tags: excel

How do i get first date and Last date from month and year |Excel |Used Spinner for Month and Year|

I have created the excel using Two Spinner one for Year and one for Month

on the basis of that the Yearly calendar is shown

if i change the month to 5 using spinner and year to 2019 using spinner then that months calendar is shown by highlighting the weekends

But issue is How do i calculate the first date and last date ?

[image: Demo image]

**My excel link Please Download at look at it suggest me formula to get first and last date**

https://www.sendspace.com/file/9xm7ox

Comment: `eoMonth()` will give last day of a month, and you can find the previous month with "-1" and add 1 day to it to give the first day of the next month.  I feel like i'm answering your title, but I'm not really sure what's all there in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first day:

```
=DATE(D3,B3,1)
```

To get the last day:

```
=EOMONTH(DATE(D3,B3,1),0)
```

Comment: Two days in a row you've come in with eoMonth!

Comment: "if only there was a way to search for that information, which is out there countless times; a type of weave interconnecting... like a web"